# How to fix the problem : "System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure."

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, docker-compose, asp.net-core-3.0

Let me explain : I have a .net core 3.0 API connected to a postgres database. I would like to perform basic CRUD operations with this API. I use swagger to display webrequest. Once I have created my context I migrate to the database which works very well however, as soon as I want to interact with my created table I have these errors that appears :

[image: ExtendedSocketException : Cannot assign requested address [::1]:5433]

[![NpgsqlException : Exception while connecting
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMBiI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMBiI.png)

The application is based on a docker container. (docker compose).
[image: Containers]

Connection to the database :

[image: ConnectionString]

[image: Connection]

My controller :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CatalogueController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly CatalogueContext _context;

    public CatalogueController(CatalogueContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Article>> GetCatalogue()
    {
        return _context.Article.ToList();
    }
}
```

My Context :

```
  public class CatalogueContext : DbContext
{
    public CatalogueContext(DbContextOptions<CatalogueContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Article> Article { get; set; }
}
```

The migration that works:
[image: migration]

My Table Article on my database (I use DBeaver) :

[image: Article]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from a comment to an answer:</sub>

> I had to change `Server = localhost` to `Server = host.docker.internal`.
> – Dyn amo   [Jan 14, 2020 at 14:46](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59734954/how-to-fix-the-problem-system-invalidoperationexception-an-exception-has-bee#comment105620948_59734954)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a service error. i.e. you might not have added services to the program.cs file.